# ORA-00932 while updating CLOB column

Tags: oracle, clob, ora-00932

I have a table with about 10 columns of type VARHCAR and size > 2000. I am trying to convert them to CLOB by using temp columns and renaming after copying data. There was no issues with 4 of these columns but I get ORA-00932 for all remaining columns. Below is the SQL repeated for each columns.

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 ADD (TEMP_CLOB CLOB );
UPDATE TABLE1 SET TEMP_CLOB=BIG_VARCHAR_COLUMN;
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 DROP COLUMN BIG_VARCHAR_COLUMN;
ALTER TABLE TABLE1 RENAME COLUMN TEMP_CLOB TO BIG_VARCHAR_COLUMN;
```

This is the error report:

```
SQL Error: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected - got CLOB
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Answer (score 0):

This was caused by triggers related to the column being modified. The fix was to disable the trigger prior to this change and then enabling them.